# Read the content of the only file in a zip file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, zip

I have a zip file in Ruby at a particular location on the file system. There is only 1 file in that zip file. I want to read the content of that file. How can I do it (without knowing the name of the file up-front)? I've tried looking at various libraries/ways but the APIs were either outdated, or the libraries weren't maintained for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RubyZip](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip):

```
require 'zip'
a = Zip::File.open(path_to_zip_file) { |z| z.first.get_input_stream.read }
```